# Wrong avatars showing in iOS app

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, profile-picture

Today I found this bug (or Jon Skeet changed his avatar ;) ).

When loading the list of users in the iOS app the images shown next to the users are different then expected. This in an example from meta.

A possible cause can be the slow internet connection.

[image: Faulting avatars]

And another one for Martijn Pieters:

[image: Faulting avatars 2]

Comment: I can't reproduce this, but I don't have a slow connection either.

Comment: So, what avatar did I get? Scroll down another 3 names or so... :-)

Comment: What kind of bug is this! I was counting on Jeff's! :-P

Comment: Got it! Don't you look pretty now?

Comment: I just reproduced this while going through a tunnel. After a second or two, the icons updated. Seems like there are cached icons from a different listing (different site maybe?) that are shown before the correct one is downloaded. Sorry @Martijn, you still had your own for me too.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: Waffles smhmaffles..

Comment: I *think* I can reproduce this with some fast scrolling; the avatars flash from a wrong one to the correct one in a fraction of a second. Most likely the iOS widget doesn't use placeholders but previously loaded images while loading the actual images over the network.

Comment: `prepareForReuse` to the rescue!

Comment: Thanks for the bug report. I'm taking a look at this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are indeed correct: looking at the user listing on a very slow connection was causing this issue to show.

Will be **fixed on 0.1.47.**

Comment: Okay. I will retest.

Comment: @PatrickHofman 0.1.47 is out you can retest.